# How to pass a parameter from a jsp to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe

I have an jsp from which i call the iframe called iframe1 .

```
<iframe id="iframe1" style="display:none;" height="430" width="675" src="Myjps.jsp" ></iframe>
```

Now i have a parameter called myActualValue, which  i am getting from a bean . Now i have to pass this parameter to iframe1 . How can I do it ?

Kindly help .

Comment: Assuming the parameter is available before the above `<iframe>` line is rendered by the JSP, why not just add it with the `src` attribute as `Myjps.jsp?param=value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside first jsp:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" style="display:none;" height="430" width="675" src="Myjps.jsp?myActualValue=<%= myActualValue %>" ></iframe>
```

Inside Iframe1 (Myjps)

```
<script>
 var myActualValue = location.search.substring(1).split("=")[1];
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass it in the URL

```
src="Myjps.jsp?myval=something"
```

Comment: So if i pass it like <iframe id="iframe1" style="display:none;" height="430" width="675" src="Myjps.jsp?myval="<%=myActualValue%> ></iframe>, do i use , request.getparameter("myval") to get it back and what if i have to pass more than one parameter ?

Comment: Yes. You can access it like you access *any other* GET parameter