# How to redirect to different jsp page with some data using iframe

Tags: jsp, iframe

I have two jsp classes named *index.jsp* and *result.jsp*. I am using iframe in index.jsp to get result.jsp into the iframe.

Further I want to send some id value in *index.jsp* to hidden field in *result.jsp*. The thing I want to know is can I send that id value with url in src clause in iframe and how can I retrieve that value.

Comment: Can you show us some code whatever you have tried so far? Also, it will help us to help you more constructively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496457/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-a-jsp-to-an-iframe.